# 遊ばにゃ損なってなもんだろうがおう！

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language

> ...遊ばにゃ損なってなもんだろうがおう！

遊ばにゃ (or にや) - can't understand what the verb form is used here...

損なって - "failing", that seems clear

なもん - have no idea how to decipher this one...

だろうがおう！"can do it" or "let's do it" and exclamation おう, depends on the previous context, as I understand?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something... the sentence doesn't really make sense if 損なって is そこなって. If 損 is そん, I would say 遊ばにゃ損ってなもんだろうが. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @dainichi-san, Right, 遊ばにゃ損'な'ってなもんだろうが sounds so awkward. I'd say 遊ばにゃ損ってなもんだろうが too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the individual parts of it are:

- 遊{あそ}ばにゃ → 遊{あそ}ばなきゃ → 遊{あそ}ばなければ (see also [遊ぶ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B6&stype=0&dtype=3))

> unless one plays/unless one has fun/unless one enjoys oneself

- [損{そん}](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%90%8D&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&index=02491300&pagenum=1)

> loss/disadvantage

- っ[てな](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA/)もん → というようなもの

> (mainly for emphasis, I don't think it changes the meaning much here)

- [だろう](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86&enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3) (the plain form of the polite でしょう)

> I think

- が

> though

- [おう！](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%86/UTF-8/)

> (an exclamation, sometimes translated as "oh!" or "hey!" etc)

> ...遊ばにゃ損ってなもんだろうがおう！
> ...遊ばなければ損というようなものでしょうがおう！
> ...It's a loss if you don't enjoy yourself I think though. *Alright*!

I think that translation loses a lot of the feel of the original colloquial text though.

**EDIT:** For the time being, I've assumed the "な" was a typo. Also hopefully fixed the exclamation part.

Comment: @user1259 Welcome to the forum!  You may already know this, but just a friendly note for the future: if someone posts an answer to your question here, make sure to "accept" the answer... so that the question has some sort of resolution for future visitors. :)  Thanks~

Comment: Above, you are glossing 損なって as son + natte. This is the verb sokonau. Hence, sokonatte.

Comment: @Dono maybe, but "sokonau" didn't make a lot of sense to me here...

Comment: @Dono, if you're able to parse the sentence with 損なって as そこなって, please explain. I personally lean towards believing that 損って was corrected to 損なって because somebody thought it was an おくりがな error

Comment: The おう is an exclamation. It's not がおう, but 「~~てなもんだろうが」+「おう」.

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the correction! I was wondering if that was an exclamation last night, but I thought it would've had a comma or something between it, e.g. "が、おう！". I should read some more Manga ^^

Comment: @cypher-san, Haha you wouldn't have to read more manga~~. Right, I too think there should be a comma. This is manga so its style tends to be so free and original I guess...