# Use な to connect the て form and もんだ

Tags: grammar

> 「ーーあの危機的状況を経て、全員生き残ってる。みんなの頑張りが、みんなの命を繋いだ。これ以上の結果は欲張りすぎ**ってなもんだ**よ。……」

Why can we use な to connect the て form and もんだ? What is this grammar phenomenon? Can we just use すぎるもんだ?

Comment: [Trying to translate 遊ばにゃ損なってなもんだろうがおう！](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5107/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a colloquial variant of これ以上の結果は欲張りすぎ**というものだよ**.

- This (っ)てな is a corrupted version of という or というような. It sounds a little dialectal or [shitamachi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62713/5010)-ish to me (typically heard in *rakugo* performances).

  - [What is な-particle doing in `ってなわけで`?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3348/5010)
  - [Meaning of てなわけで at the start of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41231/5010)
  - [How I should parse/translate てなことで at start of sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86931/5010)
- This もんだ is the same as ものだ, which you have [already asked about](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83382/5010).